# Jersey: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jersey

I am using `Jersey 2.8 Client` to post data to RESTful endpoint. The code looks like

```
    final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    final WebTarget target = client.target(url).path("inventorySummary");
    final Invocation.Builder builder = target.request().header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    final ObjectNode payload = getObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
    payload.put("startDate", DateTime.now().toString());
    payload.put("endDate", DateTime.now().plusDays(30).toString());
    payload.put("networkId", 0);

    final Response response = builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(payload, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    assertStatus(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response);
    final JsonNode jsonReply = parseResponse(response);
```

**getObjectMapper()** looks like

```
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false /* force ISO8601 */)
                .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true)
                .configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true)
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS);
    }
```

When I try to run the test, I see error as

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode, genericType=class org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you are using Jackson 1.x. Can you upgrade to Jackson 2.x and try again?

Comment: did you added genson.jar? If not, take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503748/jax-rs-jersey-json-http-500-internal-server-error/30003820#30003820

Answer (score 9):

If you ok using Jackson 1.x, then you need to the following 3 things.

**1. Add Jersey Jackson to your pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. Create a `ContextResolver`:**

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public ObjectMapperProvider() {
        defaultObjectMapper = getObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return defaultObjectMapper;
    }

    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false /* force ISO8601 */)
                .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true)
                .configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true)
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

**3. Register providers with `ClientBuilder`:**

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .register(ObjectMapperProvider.class)
        .register(JacksonFeature.class)
        .build();

final WebTarget target = client.target(url).path("inventorySummary");

final ObjectNode payload = ObjectMapperProvider.getObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
payload.put("startDate", DateTime.now().toString());
payload.put("endDate", DateTime.now().plusDays(30).toString());
payload.put("networkId", 0);

final Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .post(Entity.json(payload));

assertStatus(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response);
```

Comment: I think it would also make sense to add the imports as well, as it took me a while to figure out which dependencies to get these classes from for use with Jersey 2.x (and they are: `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api`, `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind`, `com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`, `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations`).

Answer (score 8):

I added a comment above stating that the addition of X had worked.

However, adding the following maven dependency to the pom.xml works as well, and seems like a more standard fix.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Note: The **org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes/jersey-quickstart-grizzly** maven archetype adds the dependency above by default, but commented out with the comment *"uncomment this to get JSON support"*.

Comment: Adding jersey-media-json-jackson as a pom dependency also solves the problem

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when trying to get the response from an Apache server running PHP. My response was good from the server, but Spring was complaining with the MessageBodyWriter not found for type application/json. I added the Genson dependency to my pom.xml and it fixed it!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>0.99</version>
    </dependency>
```

Documentation can be found at: https://code.google.com/p/genson/

Comment: I had the identical error using Grizzly, and adding the above to my pom.xml fixed it as well.  No other changes were required.

Comment: See my post below though for a more standard package.

Answer (score 1):

try to write the ObjectNode as a String :

```
// your code
final ObjectNode payload = getObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
payload.put("startDate", DateTime.now().toString());
payload.put("endDate", DateTime.now().plusDays(30).toString());
payload.put("networkId", 0);

// the solution
String entity = getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(payload);

final Response response = builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```