# Jersey MessageBodyWriter not found with simple POJO which has empty constructor

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

This application is just an interface between an mqtt broker and another REST interface, so it is not a full fledged REST application. (Incoming mqtt messages get processed and sent towards the REST interface via POST requests.)

It works fine if I use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and `Gson` to send POST requests with JSON payload, but I wanted to make this work with `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` and `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` too, because later on SSL support might be needed, and I already know how to provide that with Jersey. Since I think I have the right dependencies, and the POJO has a very simple structure with empty constructor, I cant find out, what causes the problem. Here are the relevant codes:

The POJO i want to send:

```
public class NumData {

private String meas_loc_site;
private int meas_loc_id;
private String gmt_event;
private String eu_db_site;
private int eu_db_id;
private int eu_type_code;
private float data_value;

public NumData(){
}

public NumData(String meas_loc_site, int meas_loc_id, String gmt_event, String eu_db_site, int eu_db_id,
        int eu_type_code, float data_value) {
    super();
    this.meas_loc_site = meas_loc_site;
    this.meas_loc_id = meas_loc_id;
    this.gmt_event = gmt_event;
    this.eu_db_site = eu_db_site;
    this.eu_db_id = eu_db_id;
    this.eu_type_code = eu_type_code;
    this.data_value = data_value;
}

public String getMeas_loc_site() {
    return meas_loc_site;
}

public void setMeas_loc_site(String meas_loc_site) {
    this.meas_loc_site = meas_loc_site;
}

public int getMeas_loc_id() {
    return meas_loc_id;
}

public void setMeas_loc_id(int meas_loc_id) {
    this.meas_loc_id = meas_loc_id;
}

public String getGmt_event() {
    return gmt_event;
}

public void setGmt_event(String gmt_event) {
    this.gmt_event = gmt_event;
}

public String getEu_db_site() {
    return eu_db_site;
}

public void setEu_db_site(String eu_db_site) {
    this.eu_db_site = eu_db_site;
}

public int getEu_db_id() {
    return eu_db_id;
}

public void setEu_db_id(int eu_db_id) {
    this.eu_db_id = eu_db_id;
}

public int getEu_type_code() {
    return eu_type_code;
}

public void setEu_type_code(int eu_type_code) {
    this.eu_type_code = eu_type_code;
}

public float getData_value() {
    return data_value;
}

public void setData_value(float data_value) {
    this.data_value = data_value;
}


}
```

The utility function which would send the request using jersey libraries:

```
    public static <T> Response sendRequest(String URI, String method, T payload) throws Exception {

    Response response = null;
    ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
    configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 30000);
    configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 30000);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);

    WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri(URI).build());
    switch (method) {
    case "GET":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").get();
        break;
    case "POST":
        System.out.println("test1");
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").post(Entity.json(payload));
        System.out.println("test2");
        break;
    case "PUT":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").put(Entity.json(payload));
        break;
    case "DELETE":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").delete();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Invalid method type was given to the Utility.sendRequest() method");
    }

    if (response == null || response.getStatus() == 500 || response.getStatus() == 400 || response.getStatus() == 404) {
        throw new Exception("Response is null or the response status code is: 400, 404 or 500");
    }

    return response;
}
```

pom.xml dependencies: (version is 2.25.1)

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also tried using `jersey-media-json-jackson`, but the issue remained.

And the stacktrace: (sorry, dont know how to fix the copy here)

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
```

SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class my.package.NumData, genericType=class my.package.NumData.
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class my.package.NumData, genericType=class my.package.NumData.
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:393)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
        at eu.mantis.mqtt_mimosa.Utility.sendRequest(Utility.java:53)
        at eu.mantis.mqtt_mimosa.Main.sendEnviromentMeasToMimosa(Main.java:155)
        at eu.mantis.mqtt_mimosa.Main.messageArrived(Main.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.deliverMessage(CommsCallback.java:477)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:184)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601842/jersey-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json-type-class)

Comment: thanks, using jackson, and adding client.register(JacksonFeature.class); worked